next js installing error npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
I want to run a next js  project from 2022 but I met this error
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno -4077
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
my package json
{
"name": "chasero-dasshboard",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start"
},
"browser": {
"image-size": false
},
"dependencies": {
"@ant-design/icons": "^4.5.0",
"@binance-chain/bsc-connector": "^1.0.0",
"@googlemaps/js-api-loader": "^1.12.10",
"@magic-ext/oauth": "^0.7.0",
"@magic-sdk/admin": "1.3.0",
"@magiclabs/ui": "0.6.1",
"@pancakeswap/uikit": "^0.34.0",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
"@types/gapi.auth2": "0.0.55",
"antd": "^4.15.4",
"chart.js": "^3.5.0",
"chartjs": "^0.3.24",
"codemirror": "^5.62.0",
"copy-to-clipboard": "^3.3.1",
"crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
"csv": "^5.5.0",
"draft-js": "^0.11.7",
"draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
"easy-autocomplete": "^1.3.5",
"emotion-ratings": "^2.0.2",
"esri-leaflet-geocoder": "^3.1.1",
"file-system": "^2.2.2",
"framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
"gapi-script": "^1.2.0",
"geojson": "^0.5.0",
"graphql": "^15.5.1",
"immutable": "^4.0.0",
"jquery": "^3.6.0",
"jquery-bar-rating": "^1.2.2",
"jspdf": "^2.4.0",
"jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.20",
"leaflet": "^1.7.1",
"leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility": "^0.1.1",
"leaflet-draw": "^1.0.4",
"leaflet-geosearch": "^3.3.2",
"magic-sdk": "^4.0.0",
"next": "10.0.9",
"next-images": "^1.7.0",
"nookies": "^2.5.2",
"nprogress": "^0.2.0",
"prismjs": "^1.24.1",
"qrcode.react": "^1.0.1",
"rc-color-picker": "^1.2.6",
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-chartjs-2": "^3.0.4",
"react-codemirror2": "^7.2.1",
"react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
"react-dom": "17.0.1",
"react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.7",
"react-leaflet": "^3.1.0",
"react-leaflet-control": "^2.1.2",
"react-leaflet-draw": "^0.19.8",
"react-leaflet-markercluster": "^3.0.0-rc1",
"react-player": "^2.9.0",
"react-redux": "^7.2.2",
"react-simple-code-editor": "^0.11.0",
"rxjs": "^7.3.0",
"sass": "^1.32.8",
"styled-components": "^5.2.3",
"survey-analytics": "^1.8.58",
"survey-creator": "^1.8.58",
"survey-pdf": "^1.8.58",
"survey-react": "^1.8.58",
"surveyjs-widgets": "^1.8.78",
"web3": "^1.3.5",
"xlsx": "^0.17.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"json-loader": "^0.5.7"
}
}
can any one help me please
try to run next js project

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To integrate SurveyJS within Next.js, please follow this GitHub example: SurveyJS + Next.js Quickstart Template.
